# Can't mount ntfs disk with the certain set of permissions (root's ones)

Tags: 12.10, mount, permissions, ntfs

I need to mount an `ntfs` disk with the certain permission and for an user `alex` be able to have the same as `root` would have.

Here is my file `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sda2 /media/win_disk ntfs-3g rwx,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0
```

When I try to mount it, it says

```
An error occurred while accessing '421.8 GiB Hard Disk (ntfs)', the system responded: The requested operation has failed.: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sda2 on /media/win_disk
```

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Try adding the `user` option, so: `/dev/sda2 /media/win_disk ntfs-3g rwx,user,locale=en_US.utf8 0 0`. But also, I've never seen this `rwx` option.

Comment: @Alaa, what if I want it to have rwx permissions, how do I do that then if not use rwx?

Comment: `rwx` permissions for who? The owner (user), group, or other? To control permissions, you'll need to use the `umask` option, and to control ownership, you need to use the `uid` and `gid` options. Who do you want to be the owner of all files under the partition? You? The usual approach is that you make yourself the owner, and give yourself `rwx` permissions.

Comment: @Alaa, rwx for everybody.

Comment: Look at my answer and the comment there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below.

1. We'll unmount the partition, just in case.

   ```
   sudo umount /media/win_disk
   ```
2. We'll delete the mount point and recreate it to make sure that it has the correct permissions.

   ```
   sudo rm -r /media/win_disk
   sudo mkdir /media/win_disk
   ```
3. Open up your `/etc/fstab`, delete the line that you added, and add this line instead:

   ```
   /dev/sda2    /media/win_disk    ntfs-3g     rw,auto,user,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0    0
   ```

   This will:

   - **`auto`**: automount the partition.
   - **`rw`**: mount it as read-write.
   - **`user`**: allow users to mount/unmount it.
   - **`uid=1000`**: make the user with user ID 1000 as the owner of everything in the partition.
   - **`gid=46`**: make the group `plugdev` as the group owner (don't mind this).
   - **`umask=003`**: make everything under the partition have the permissions `-rwxrwxr--`.

   All of this basically means that you will be the owner, and you'll have `rwx` permissions for everything. It will also automount the partition when you reboot the machine. If you don't want it to automount, just change `auto` to `noauto`.

   > Note: see that `uid=1000`? You need to change that to be your user ID. It is most probably 1000, but just to be sure, do the command `id` and look at the number after `uid=###(your_username)`. If that number is not 1000, then change `uid=` to be that number.
4. Save the file and close it, then do

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

   You should not get an error, and you should find your partition mounted. If you get an error, **do not restart your machine** and tell us what the error is.

For more information about `fstab` and its options, visit the [**Fstab Ubuntu help page**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab).

Comment: If you want to give everybody `rwx`, so all the files and folders will have permissions like this: `-rwxrwxrwx`, then change the `umask` option to be `umask=000`.

Comment: that's great. will it be mounted  automatically every time as the system starts?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned underneath the bullet points, you can change `auto` to `noauto`. That way, it won't be mounted automatically at system startup.

Comment: thanks. but nonetheless, I saw many threads where people asked how to make a disk mount automatically and they suggested them other, more complicated solutions. it was weird, did no one know about `auto` and `noauto`?

Comment: That's weird, because it's common to use `auto`. I think those other complicated solutions eventually end up modifying the `fstab` file to use `auto` through some scripts. Just a point to note: if you're using `noauto`, the last command in my answer `sudo mount -a` will not mount the partition. To mount it, you'll have to do `sudo mount /dev/sda2` (or `sudo mount /media/win_disk`). It should then read all the options from the `fstab` file to give the proper permissions and ownership.